# Delete duplicates after coding response on one variable R

Tags: r, duplicates

Overall aim: Delete duplicates after coding response on one variable

I have a dataset where an individual can select multiple options on a variable [e.g. Country Code]. I want to delete the duplicates but first I want to make sure that I capture all of the information.

For example Country Code, where options 1-5 is Europe and 6-10 is Africa- I created variables that coded Europe= 1 if Country Code =1:5 and 0 if 6:10 (visa versa for Africa).

| ID | Country Code | Europe | Africa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 | 0 | 1 |

But I want to see if they answered 1 to both, and then delete the duplicate IDs.
Hence I want to create a dataset that looks like this:

| ID | Europe | Africa | Both |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I've tried this:

`aggregate(x=Europe,by=list(ID),FUN=sum))`
to create a sumEurope (followed by sumAfrica) to then say "if sumEurope*sumAfica >0 = 1"
However, the above code has an error that the "Assigned data..must be compatible with existing data." as there are more existing rows than assigned rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `summarise` with `max` `across` `Europe` and `Africa` and then an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Europe, Africa), max)) %>% 
  mutate(Both = ifelse(Africa == 1 & Europe == 1, 1, 0))
```

```
     ID Europe Africa  Both
  <int>  <int>  <int> <dbl>
1     1      1      1     1
2     2      1      1     1
3     3      0      1     0
```

data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), CountryCode = c(1L, 
4L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 7L), Europe = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Africa = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hello, this produced output in my console but not a "both variable" in my dataframe. I am unsure what the last step in the "data:" means though.

Comment: If the data function allows a new data frame to be made. The probably is there are too many rows for me to manually enter. How can I work around this ?

Comment: You have to assign it to an object like `data <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(Europe, Africa), max)) %>% 
  mutate(Both = ifelse(Africa == 1 & Europe == 1, 1, 0))`. Then you can call it with data.

Answer (score 1):

In BASE R:

```
transform(+aggregate(cbind(Europe, Africa)~ID, df, any), Both = Europe * Africa)
  ID Europe Africa Both
1  1      1      1    1
2  2      1      1    1
3  3      0      1    0
```

If you dont mind the logical values:

```
transform(aggregate(cbind(Europe, Africa)~ID, df, any), Both = Europe * Africa)
  ID Europe Africa Both
1  1   TRUE   TRUE    1
2  2   TRUE   TRUE    1
3  3  FALSE   TRUE    0
```

Comment: Unfortunately this comes up with an error stating that the arguments imply differing number of rows